# Check if a checkbox is ticked in a Screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, screen-flow, test-automation

Hi all I am using a screen flow and here if all the checkboxes I have added in a screen is checked then a field update should happen in an object.
[image]

Here I have added all the checkboxes in the screen. But how do I check if these are checked. Only then I can provide an update record.
I should able to save the screen flow even if any one of the four checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Do you want the validation on the screen itself or based on the checkboxes if any of the check box is checked then only update should happen if not checked update should not happen. Can you clarify it.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala  No it is not necessary to be on the screen .Once I choose the checkboxes and save,if even any of these are not checked then the update shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding a Decision box and validating if the values are true or not and then add the update element based on that as shown below.

[image]

And add the update element based on this decision box as below.

[image]